# How to fix the size of my Qt window?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a `QWidget`, the parent class for all my other widgets. In Qt Designer I set `width = 600` and `height = 400` for the `QWidget`. My size Policy is `[Fixed, Fixed, 0, 0]`.

But if I start my the application the QWidgets size is at least `2500*400`. How could I fix the size at application start to `600*400`?

Comment: Maybe you have set size policy of central widget rather than the mainwindow. Or you can set the size at the last of construction of mainwindow.

Comment: Did you set the max size too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size policy on a toplevel layout is meaningless if you don't set the size constraint as well via `QLayout::setSizeConstraint`. It is the size constraint that links the layout to the toplevel widget's size.